# Running a Java Mobile application in Java Standard Edition

Tags: java, java-me

I have a Java Mobile application using CLDC 1.0 and MIDP 2.0 and I would like to port it to Java standard edition so that I can demonstrate the application on my company website. Can anyone give me any advice on how I would do this or suggest any tools that could help?

**Links**

- [GamesOnDeck](http://www.gamesondeck.com/feature/1491/ditch_the_emulators_how_to_code_.php?page=1): Contains information on implementing quite a few basic classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to port to J2SE because MicroEmu could help: http://www.microemu.org/

Take a look at Web Start demonstration section with JNLP: http://www.microemu.org/microemu-webstart/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Please see [ME application web site](https://meapplicationdevelopers.dev.java.net/) as reference.
It uses [mpowerplayer](http://mpowerplayer.com/) emulator to run Java ME application from PC.

Comment: It seems that I'd either have to pay mpowerplayer to use their emulator or open source my application. Unfortunately, I can't do either.